# How to allow a user to enter Windows Environment Variables in a JFileChooser dialog

Tags: java, environment-variables, jfilechooser

I am using `JFileChooser` for my Java GUI to allow the user to browse for files to import.  I am using `TestComplete` to create some tests for my program, and need the ability to use environment variables in the `JFileChooser` window "File Name:" text field.

For example, I want to be able to type the following line into the "File Name:" text box...

```
%TEST_FILES%\file_set_1\testfile.xml
```

Does anyone know how to enable the `JFileChooser` to accept Windows Environment Variables.

The reason I want to be able to use Environment Variables is because the TestComplete tests are going to be run on a variety of computers, and everyone might have their test files in a different location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `JFileChooser` doesn't do this automatically, but you can do it yourself by interpreting the content of filename string as returned from the `JFileChooser` in the accept handler.

So we have a routine to get all the environment variables, which are made into lower case to make them match more easily:

```
private Map<String, String> getEnv() {
    Map<String, String> fromEnv = System.getenv();
    Map<String, String> toReturn = new HashMap<>();
    for (String key : fromEnv.keySet()) {
        toReturn.put(key.toLowerCase(), fromEnv.get(key));
    }
    return toReturn;
}
```

This will be used by a routine that expands the filename, which is relatively simple - simply find the `%VAR%` items, and replace them. In the case of an unmatched variable, just break out, leaving the string partially parsed.

```
private String expandFileName(String filename) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("%([^%]*)%");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(filename);
    Map<String, String> env = getEnv();
    while (m.find()) {
        String var = m.group(1);
        String value = env.get(var.toLowerCase());
        if (value != null) {
            filename = filename.replaceAll("%" + var + "%",
                    Matcher.quoteReplacement(value));
        } else {
            return filename;
        }
        m = p.matcher(filename);
    }
    return filename;
}
```

Next, we need to use a subclass of JFileChooser to deal with the attempt to use a filename, so we need to override the `approveSelection` method, get the filename, expand it and try to determine the file in question. Because this code is going to be used in an open dialog, I took some liberties in the accept routine where it requires the file to exist rather than returning with the expanded name of the file.

```
public void approveSelection() {
    File f = getSelectedFile();
    // remove the CWD from the string - leaving the text from the edit box
    String prena = f.toString().replace(getCurrentDirectory().toString() + File.separator, "");
    String name = expandFileName(prena);
    if (prena.equals(name)) {
        if (!f.exists()) {
            return;
        }
        // This expanded to the same, and the file is there
        super.approveSelection();
        return;
    }
    // try to use the name
    f = new File(name);
    if (f.isFile()) { // file, ok
        setSelectedFile(f);
        super.approveSelection();
    } else if (f.isDirectory()) { // change to dir
        setCurrentDirectory(f);
        return;
    } else if (!f.exists()) { // try with cwd and name in field
        f = new File(getCurrentDirectory(), name);
        if (f.exists()) {
            setSelectedFile(f);
            super.approveSelection();
        }
    }
}
```

The logic is rather convoluted, but the point is to try to catch most of the conditions that you would consider.

The long and the short of it is that you have to do it manually, but the amount of work required is really not that much.

You can then glue them all into a:

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser() {
    // put in all the routines as listed earlier
};
chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(true);
int choice = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
if (choice == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    String name = chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could dynamically generate a batch script and then execute it?

Why not just ask the user where the file is?